# Where are compiler errors shown in Xcode 11? C++ code

Tags: c++, xcode

I am getting build failure in Xcode 11. I cannot see any compiler errors, however. I just see the message "Build Failed". In the upper right, I hit the box with the line at the bottom. That shows two sub-windows at the bottom. On the left, the window has a label "Auto". On the right, the window has the label "All output". These are at the bottom. However, nothing appears in them even when there is clearly a compiler error. Is there a compiler error window in Xcode? I also see errors inserted in the source window itself. Maybe that's all there is?

Comment: At the top of the left column of a project window you will see 9 small icons. The rightmost one, a speech bubble, is where build logs are found. Click there, the list of builds will show, click on a build to select it and the build log will show. Long errors will show on the right side with a disclosure bubble.

Comment: There's also a triangular-shaped icon in that window which lists all build issues.